# Why wont this regex match?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with the following format:

```
/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Logout Successful!" = "Logout Successful!";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"London" = "London";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Low Balance" = "Low Balance";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Low-Cost Call" = "Low-Cost Call";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Making A Low Cost Call" = "Making A Low Cost Call";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Making FREE Calls" = "Making FREE Calls";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"MNO" = "MNO";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"more free credit" = "more free credit";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"My Phone Number" = "My Phone Number";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"My Purchase is Missing" = "My Purchase is Missing";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Next" = "Next";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"NO" = "NO";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"No" = "No";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"No Balance" = "No Balance";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Post Successful" = "Post Successful";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Post to %d %@ Facebook Wall" = "Post to %1$d %2$@ Facebook Wall";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Post to Facebook Wall" = "Post to Facebook Wall";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Post To My Facebook Wall" = "Post To My Facebook Wall";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Post to My Wall" = "Post to My Wall";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Posted" = "Posted";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Posting" = "Posting";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Posting to Your Facebook Wall..." = "Posting to Your Facebook Wall...";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"PQRS" = "PQRS";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Proceed" = "Proceed";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Proceed, Don't Show Again" = "Proceed, Don't Show Again";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Processing..." = "Processing...";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Purchase History" = "Purchase History";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Rates" = "Rates";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Remind me later" = "Remind me later";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Restart" = "Restart";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Retry Failed" = "Retry Failed";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Return to %@ after each call ends" = "Return to %@ after each call ends";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Return To App After Call" = "Return To App After Call";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Roaming Support" = "Roaming Support";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Roaming Warning!" = "Roaming Warning!";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Searching..." = "Searching...";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"See The Time In Any Country" = "See The Time In Any Country";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Select All" = "Select All";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Select the number for an iPhone with %@" = "Select the number for an iPhone with %@";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Send" = "Send";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Send a Text Message" = "Send a Text Message";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Sending..." = "Sending...";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Settings" = "Settings";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Show All" = "Show All";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Show Me How" = "Show Me How";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Show Selected" = "Show Selected";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Sign In" = "Sign In";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Signing in..." = "Signing in...";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Skip" = "Skip";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"SMS" = "SMS";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Speed Dial & Favorites" = "Speed Dial & Favorites";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Store" = "Store";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Success" = "Success";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Success!" = "Success!";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Support" = "Support";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"System Status" = "System Status";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Tapjoy Offers" = "Tapjoy Offers";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Tell %d Friend%@" = "Tell %1$d Friend%2$@";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Tell Facebook Friends" = "Tell Facebook Friends";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Tell Friends" = "Tell Friends";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Tell Friends About %@" = "Tell Friends About %@";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Tell via E-Mail" = "Tell via E-Mail";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Tell via SMS" = "Tell via SMS";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Test Call" = "Test Call";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Text Message" = "Text Message";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Try Again" = "Try Again";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Turning Caller ID ON/OFF" = "Turning Caller ID ON/OFF";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"TUV" = "TUV";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Tweet to Friends" = "Tweet to Friends";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Unable to Call" = "Unable to Call";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Unable to Check Talk Time" = "Unable to Check Talk Time";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Unable to connect." = "Unable to connect.";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Unable to Create Account" = "Unable to Create Account";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Unable to Purchase" = "Unable to Purchase";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Unable to Sign In" = "Unable to Sign In";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Unknown" = "Unknown";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"unknown caller" = "unknown caller";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Unselect All" = "Unselect All";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Updating Your Phone Number" = "Updating Your Phone Number";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"VoIP %@" = "VoIP %@";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"WARNING!" = "WARNING!";
```

I want to parse this using a regex to get just the keys and values without surrounding quotes into a dictionary:

```
def load_replacement_dict(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        resultDict = {}

        dictionary_regex = re.compile('"([^"]*)" = "([^"]*)"',)

        for result in dictionary_regex.finditer(content):
            resultDict[result.group(1)] = result.group(2)

        for key, value in resultDict.items():
            print (key+" = "+value).decode('utf-8')

        return resultDict
```

The first subgroup matches but when I add anything after that it ceases to match. I tried using space, using \s and nothing seems to match the spaces around the equals signs. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I found that if I remove the unicode byte order marker from the beginning of the file, the regex then works. Not the solution obviously but maybe a clue on how the regex can be modified?

Comment: [Regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html) can help you.  As it is, I don't know what you want or what you don't want, but the regex in your code is missing literal double-quotes around the second capture group.

Comment: Edited to fix the quotes. I had them but I was deleting stuff to try to make it work and forgot to readd for the question.

Comment: is it possible for an engineer to provide a comment?

Comment: Possible but in practice we don't

Comment: Kirby, this question has mutated since it was first asked - can you include the OLD and NEW versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being an encoding issue. The file was UTF-16. Once I added:

```
with codecs.open(file_name, 'r', 'utf-16') as f:
```

the regex works fine.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that what you are trying to achieve can be done more easily with string methods instead of regular expressions:

```
>>> s = '"A Key With \"quotes\" in it" = " Another Value "'
>>> l,r = [v.strip().strip('"').strip() for v in s.split('=')]
>>> l,r
 ('A Key With "quotes" in it', 'Another Value')
```

The escaping will be preserved, it gets lost above only because of the way I created the string. I you read the text from a file, then what happens is:

```
In [1]: lines = open('x.txt').read().splitlines()

In [2]: for s in lines: print [v.strip().strip('"').strip() for v in s.split('=')]
   ...: 
['Some Key', 'Some Value']
['Another Key', 'Another Value']
['A Key With \\"quotes\\" in it', 'Another Value']
```

Comment: This is the best approach.

Comment: `s` should be `'"A Key With \\"quotes\\" in it" = " Another Value "'`.

Comment: Keys and values must remain escaped

Comment: What if there are `=` signs inside the quotes?

Comment: I mean, is it an expected situation?

Comment: It's an xcode localization file so I guess there's no reason the text of key or value couldn't contain equals.

Comment: I added a bit of the datafile to the question. Forgot to mention there's comments in the data file as well.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the escaped quotes problem, you can use this

```
"((?:[^"]+|(?<=\\)")*)" = "((?:[^"]+|(?<=\\)")*)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't checking for quotes around the value in the regex, so it can't match.  Also, to handle escaped quotes inside of a key or value, I belive this should cover it:

```
dictionary_regex = re.compile(r'"((?:(?:\\")|[^"])*)" = "((?:(?:\\")|[^"])*)"')
```

Answer (score 0):

With the sample key value pairs that have been posted the following regex seems to be working:

```
re.compile('"(.*)" = "(.*)"')
```

Am I missing out something?